# Unreachable statement Error While inflating a fragment view

Tags: java, android-fragments

I'm training to create an inflate function. I am a beginner in Android,.The bold text returns an error "Unreachable statement"

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container,
                false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        **View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);**
    showCountTextView = fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView_first);
    return fragmentFirstLayout;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code again.
you are having two return statements. Remove one of them and try again

your corrected should either be

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container,
                false);
```

or

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        **View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);**
    showCountTextView = fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView_first);
    return fragmentFirstLayout;
    }
```